# Prime's notation in RFC3526 about Diffie Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

In RFC3526, the prime is presented by
2^1536 - 2^1472 - 1 + 2^64 * { [2^1406 pi] + 741804 } form

I wanna know the "[2^1406 pi]" part means what

THKS

Comment: I am interested in this method for producing the prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [] notation represents the greatest integer or [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function) function. Therefore [2^1406 pi] means multiply pi (3.141...) by 2^1406 and throw away the fractional part. Enter `Floor[2^1406 * Pi]` into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to see the result.

Comment: Thanks for help, did you know why choose this form to represent primes?

Comment: I believe the primes are chosen to make the Montgomery and Barret modular reduction schemes most efficient, as well as use Pi as a source of "random" bits.